# Finding local maxima for 3d matrix

Tags: matlab, geometry, hough-transform

I am trying to implement Hough transform in Matlab to find circles in a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkb1.png).

In the accumulator matrix, the global maximum is `105` at `A(32,31,24)`. So I'm able to get this: [max circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC0OV.jpg)

The problem is, how can i find the local maxima to find the rest of the circles?

I wrote this to find `A(i,j,k)` which is bigger than the 26 adjacent points (26-Connected voxel neighborhood):

```
[i j k]=find(A~=0) ;
f=0;
for s=1:size(i)
    if(i(s)~=100&&j(s)~=100&&k(s)~=141&&i(s)~=1&&j(s)~=1&&k(s)~=1)
    if     (A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s),k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s),k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)-1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)+1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)-1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)+1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)+1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)-1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s),k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s),k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s),k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)-1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)+1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)-1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)+1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)+1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)-1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s),k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s),k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s),k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)-1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)+1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)-1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)+1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)+1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)-1,k(s)-1))
        f=f+1
        i(s)
        j(s)
        k(s)
    end
    end
end
```

Why i never got these correct `i`,`j`,`k` and `f` is always `0`? I think i should at least find `(32,31,24)` and `f=1`?

Can anyone help me ?
Thank you so much!

The complete code is here:

```
im=imread('C:\Users\dell\Desktop\tp-complet\Hough\four.png');

sigma = 0.3;
gausFilter = fspecial('gaussian',[5 5],sigma);
sobelFilter=fspecial('sobel');
img=imfilter(im,gausFilter,'replicate');

ims=edge(img,'sobel');

rmax=size(im,1);
cmax=size(im,2);
radmax=round(sqrt(rmax^2+cmax^2));

for i=1:rmax
   for j=1:cmax
      for k=1:radmax
          A(i,j,k)=0;
      end
  end
end

[r c]=find(ims==1);
length=size(r);

for k=1:length
    for l=1:rmax
    for m=1:cmax
        if((l~=r(k))&&(m~=c(k)))
            x=sqrt((l-r(k))^2+(m-c(k))^2);
            x=round(x);
            A(l,m,x)=A(l,m,x)+1;
        end
   end
   end
end

[i j k]=find(A~=0) ;
f=0;
for s=1:size(i)
    if(i(s)~=100&&j(s)~=100&&k(s)~=141&&i(s)~=1&&j(s)~=1&&k(s)~=1)
    if     (A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s),k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s),k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)-1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)+1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)-1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)+1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)+1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)-1,k(s))&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s),k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s),k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s),k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)-1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)+1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)-1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)+1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)+1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)-1,k(s)+1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s),k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s),k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s),k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)-1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s),j(s)+1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)-1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)-1,j(s)+1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)+1,k(s)-1)&&A(i(s),j(s),k(s))>A(i(s)+1,j(s)-1,k(s)-1))
        f=f+1
        i(s)
        j(s)
        k(s)
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: It's not clear what picture you're using, which file is C:\Users\dell\Desktop\tp-complet\Hough\four.png?

Comment: @TTT Hi, "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\tp-complet\Hough\four.png" is the picture that i met in the link "picture origin"  which is 100*100   ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the image processing toolbox, so cannot readily run your code.  However, a quick review indicates to me that you're using the [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function incorrectly.  When provided with 3 outputs (as you have it), find doesn't return the 3D indices, but rather row, column, and a vector of the values.  That means that `k` is just a giant vector of 1's, and so your `for` loop's `if k(s)~=1` statement is never satisfied.  You should do something like `[i,j,k]=ind2sub(size(A),find(A~=0))` if you instead want the 3D indices.

Also, FYI, this:

```
for i=1:rmax
   for j=1:cmax
      for k=1:radmax
          A(i,j,k)=0;
      end
  end
end
```

Can be replaced with `A=zeros(rmax,cmax,radmax);`.

Comment: Hi @刘思遥, If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @MattSchmatt thank you，i dont know this before，sorry for that.      :p